# blazor google maps refreshes on programmatic marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app in which I place markers on a google map.  The end user can click on a marker to have it update the selected value of a "select location" dropdown displayed below the map -- this works perfectly.

If the user selects a map location from the dropdown, I call a function, "clickPin", that programatically clicks the pin for that map location.

The trouble is that immediately after the marker is clicked programatically I see the Marker pop up for a split second, then the map refreshes.  I'm not sure if it's the dropdown acting like a submit button (I don't *think* it is...?), the script forcing a reload, or something built into Google Maps.

I have searched all over google and stackoverflow, and I have not been able to find a solution that even mentions this problem.

Here are the important parts of my code:

First, the scripts to deal with the maps:

```
var mapOptions = null;
var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;
var markers = [];

function initialize(coords) {
    mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.68484978380786, -86.60681036623693),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function addpins(name, lat, lng, desc) {
    var data = { name, lat, lng, desc };
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: data.name
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.desc);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(marker, data);
    (function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            Array.from(document.querySelector("#test").options).forEach(function (option_element) {
                let option_text = option_element.text;

                if (option_text === marker.title) {
                    option_element.selected = true;
                }
            });
        });
    })(marker, map, infoWindow);
}

function clickPin(txt) {
    markers.forEach(function (m) {
        let val = m.title;
        if (txt === val) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'click');
        }
    });
}
```

Second, The razor page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div id="map" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
                    
<select id="test" value="@testId" @onchange="@ClickPin">
     @foreach (var inf in Infos)
     {
        <option value="@inf.Name">@inf.Name</option>
     }
</select>
```

Third, calling "clickPin":

```
private int? testId { get; set; }

internal async Task ClickPin(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var selVal = e.Value.ToString();
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("clickPin", new string[] { selVal });
}
```

I'm hoping I'm missing something incredibly simple.  Any suggestions are welcome.

...and it turns out that I *was* missing something incredibly simple.  ::sigh::

In my OnAfterRenderAsync function:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    Infos = await Info.GetAll();
    if (firstRender) { StateHasChanged(); }
    else { await LoadMapPins(); }
}
```

should read as:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    Infos = await Info.GetAll();
    if (firstRender) { StateHasChanged(); await LoadMapPins(); }
    //else { await LoadMapPins(); }
}
```

I was running LoadMapPins anytime the page refreshed. ::sigh::

Sorry for the wasted time.  I'll leave the question here, though -- maybe someone else can get some use out of it.

Thanks,
Carthax

Answer (score 1):

...and it turns out that I was missing something incredibly simple. ::sigh::

In my OnAfterRenderAsync function:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    Infos = await Info.GetAll();
    if (firstRender) { StateHasChanged(); }
    else { await LoadMapPins(); }
}
```

should read as:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    Infos = await Info.GetAll();
    if (firstRender) { StateHasChanged(); await LoadMapPins(); }
    //else { await LoadMapPins(); }
}
```

I was running LoadMapPins anytime the page refreshed. ::sigh::

Sorry for the wasted time. I'll leave the question here, though -- maybe someone else can get some use out of it.